# Norton equivalent with dependent source

Tags: norton

[image]

The figure above illustrates a circuit with VCVS and its Norton equivalent model as seen from Port B. Given that Vo=5V,A=2,R1=1Ω,R2=3Ω,R3=5Ω, determine the Norton current IN and Norton resistance RN

**Attempts:**
I calculated Vout=7.857 V; u=5.714 V. I don't know how to calculate the Norton resistance, since the dependent source 2u cannot be suppressed to calculate the resistance looking from the output.

Comment: For those who are searching for this problems, the below hint from Curd is correct. That 's all you need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the Norton (or Thevenin) Eq. is to determine the short circuit current \$i_{SC}\$ and the open circuit voltage \$v_{OS}\$ of your circuit.

I.e. you have to analyze following two variants of your circuit:

- With a short between the terminals, find the current that is going through the short and
- with the terimals open, find the voltage across the terminals.

The Norton (or Thevenin) resistance then is \$R_N = R_{Th} = v_{OC} / i_{SC}\$.
The Norton current source value is \$i_N = i_{SC}\$.
(The Thevenin voltage source value would be \$v_{Th} = v_{OC}\$)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I thought I need to suppress the independent voltage source +5V BEFORE do a shorting between A and B.

Comment: Well, there *is* another method, that would require to consider the "dead" circuit (i.e. all independend sources made inactive) but most of the time I prefere the way I have described in the answer.